# Is inverse kinematics possible without additional reference objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was looking at this tutorial: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html

In that tutorial, they change the body position of hands, head etc, by setting a target object to hold or look at.

In this project: https://hackaday.com/2016/01/23/amazing-imu-based-motion-capture-suit-turns-you-into-a-cartoon/

The guy access the blender api, and directly sets the transform of several bones.

Is it possible to do the same in Unity ? I do not need any assistance with getting data from sensors etc. I'm just looking for information on what is the equivalent API in unity to directly set the orientation of specific body parts of a skeleton at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [SkinnedMeshRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.html).

When you import a model from some 3d soft, such as blender, it will have SkinnedMeshRenderer component.

What you would want too check out is `SkinnedMeshRenderer.bones`, which get you the array of bones (as an array of `Transform`) used to control its pose. You can modify its elements, thus affecting the pose. So you can do stuff like this:

```
var bones = this.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().bones;
bones[0].localRotation = bones[0].localRotation *  Quaternion.Euler(0f, 45f, 0f);
```

Just play around with it, it is the best way to see.

For more advanced manipulations, you can also set your own array of bones and specify their weights, with `SetBlendShapeWeight` / `GetBlendShapeWeight`, but this is probably more than what you need.